# Construction of Probability Measure in Infinite Dimensional Space

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

My question is relatively simple, though the topic is not. I am trying to navigate the subject of Probability Measures in Abstract Spaces. I am doing so without a guide/mentor, so I am probably not efficient. But I have discovered a thread from the schools of Alexandroff, Prohorov and Sazonov. (Savonov's theorem on continuity of characteristic functionals in the "S-topology" was my original stimulus.) The development is arduous, but I do have some starting knowledge, for example, familiarity with Rudin, Loeve and Halmos.

Alexandroff constructs a "charge" using a modification of the space (which I so far only vaguely appreciate) and a construction similar to the construction of a measure representing a linear functional in compact Hausdorf space. Of course, the spaces of interest for probability and stochastic processes are not locally compact.

In my review of the classical case I note that Rudin constructs a measure on a sigma-algebra that contains the Borel sets while Halmos constructs a Borel measure per se. Halmos appears to do this without utilizing Urysohn. Am I correct that Rudin's treatment requires Urysohn in order to construct the more general measure? Or is Urysohn implicit in Halmos' treatment? Am I even on the right track thinking that the less general "charge" is serving in the infinite-dimensional case where a measure would be used in, for example, finite-dimensional spaces?

By the way, I own a copy of Borgachev, which has a (brief) modern treatment of the topic... I will certainly access that too.

Thanks in advance for any guidance in general. If anyone is interested in being a "reading course" advisor, I would love to connect. I am not sure if this is the forum to search in. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to find such a person. I am not presently matriculated in any school.

References:
Halmos: Measure Theory

Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis

Loeve: Probability Theory

Bogachev: Measure Theory

Alexandroff: A. D. Alexandroff, Additive set-functions in abstract spaces, Rec. Math. [Mat. Sbornik] N.S., 1943, Volume 55, 169–238

Prohorov: CONVERGENCE OF RANDOM PROCESSES AND LIMIT THEOREMS IN PROBABILITY THEORY, THEORY OF PROBABILITY AND ITS APPLICATIONS Volume I  Number 2 1956

Sazanov: A REMARK ON CHARACTERISTIC FUNCTIONALS, Theory of Probability & Its ApplicationsVol. 3, Iss. 2 (1958)